# PyCharm console doesn't clear

Tags: pycharm

So I recently had my machine re-imaged and a few odd things are happening in my new PyCharm install.

First of all, I use a PS1 definition in my `bash_profile`

```
PS1='\n\n\e[1;34mLOCAL: \@ $PWD  \n\n\e[0;30m'
```

Which prints out the time and current working directory in a different color so that it's easy for me to navigate output.

In a regular terminal, that makes my command line look like this:

```
LOCAL: 12:01 PM /Users/me  

ls
Applications                Pictures
Desktop                     Public
Library                     anaconda
```

However, in PyCharm, the console also prints out my interpreter path:

```
(/Users/me/anaconda) 

LOCAL: 12:01 PM /Users/me  

ls
Applications                Pictures
Desktop                     Public
Library                     anaconda
```

Which I can turn off on every project individually by turning off virtualenv activation, however, if I try to cycle through history using the up arrow, the line does not clear fully.

```
LOCAL: 12:01 PM /Users/me  

echo "this is prior to hitting up arrow"
this is prior to hitting up arrow
(/Users/me/anaconda) 

LOCAL: 12:01 PM /Users/me  

echo "techo "after hitting the up arrow twice, this line is prepended by 'echo t'"
after hitting the up arrow twice, this line is prepended by 'echo t'
```

Any idea what might be causing this behavior and how I could get PyCharm's console to behave like the regular terminal across all of my projects?

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around a bit, I realized that it can be fixed by modifying my PS1 from this:

```
PS1='\n\n\e[1;34mLOCAL: \@ $PWD  \n\n\e[0;30m'
```

to this:

```
PS1='\n\n\e[1;34mLOCAL: \@ $PWD  \e[0;30m\n\n'
```

It seems like the escaped color code is reserving space in the terminal that doesn't get flushed out properly.  I don't know why this is the case in PyCharm and not in the standard terminal but this did solve the issue for me.